# Error Field Repository in Controller.Controller required a bean of type 'Controller.Repository' that could not be found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to connect my Controller to Repository in one of the spring application but I'm getting an error saying "Field tweetRepository in TweetsController.TweetsController required a bean of type 'TweetsController.TweetRepository' that could not be found."

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance. I've attached code samples as well.

`TwitterApplication.java`

```
package SpringMVC.Twitter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("AuthController")
@ComponentScan("TweetsController")
public class TwitterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TwitterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`TwitterController.java`

```
package TweetsController;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class TweetsController {

    @Autowired
    private TweetRepository tweetRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/tweets")
    public Iterable<TweetsContent> getAllTweets() {
        return tweetRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("tweet/{id}")
    public Optional<TweetsContent> getTweet(@PathVariable int id) {
        return tweetRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tweets")
    public boolean addTweet(@RequestBody TweetsContent tweet) {
        TweetsContent t = tweetRepository.save(new TweetsContent(tweet.getTitle(), tweet.getContent()));
        if (t != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

`TwitterRepository.java`

```
package TweetsController;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TweetRepository extends CrudRepository<TweetsContent, Integer> { }
```

Comment: Is there spring-data-jpa in the classpath?

Comment: @SurajGautam: I didn't get your question. This is my first hands on with Spring, so apologies for dumb follow ups. Are asking if I've added spring-data-jpa in my pom.xml file?

Comment: Ok, in the code above, could you please put the package as well? I think you have problems with scanning.

Comment: @SurajGautam Edited the code to show my packages as well.

Comment: I suggest following the best practices as mentioned in the Spring Boot reference guide. Move your your repository and controller either into the same package as your `TwitterApplication` or in a sub package thereof. Then remove the `@CompoentScan` and it will work. Else you need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories ` for the package containing the repos. But by not following the suggest format you loose some of the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Add the spring data dependency on your pom:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do have that dependency in my `pom.xml` file and I'm still facing this issue. Thanks though for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this too. 
@ComponentScan("TweetRepository")

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use @ComponentScan("AuthController") and @ComponentScan("TweetsController") because if you use @SpringBootApplication, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation. But you need to put TwitterApplication like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify `@ComponentScan` in your `TwitterApplication`, because spring boot application is scanning its own directory at the startup. and remove the `@Repository`
annotation from your repository class, it is also not needed.